# Jira Software Responsibility Matrix

Tags: jira

I'm setting up a new Jira Software instance and I'm trying to establish some needed processes, rules and guidelines as well to make sure everybody knows what to expect and who to contact for support.

So I want to create a matrix with all (common) Jira Software features and define who is allowed to perform which action. For example:

1. Scrum Masters can edit board settings and ticket layout, but (external) testers can not.
2. Administrators invite new users into Jira but everybody else can not.
3. Project Leads can delete tickets, but Scrum Masters, Developers and Testers can not

So far I didn't find a blueprint of some sort. I want to avoid to write down each Jira function by myself. Assigns responsibilities by myself is okay with me, but identifying everything seems quite annoying to me. I'm thinking along the lines of a RACI or DACI matrix. But a (mostly) complete feature list would suffice for starters.

Comment: Is this the cloud based Jira or self-hosted?

Comment: Self hosted but the most recent version. Plugin-features are not important.

Answer (score 0):

To find all the possible actions you can perform in Jira, refer to these two places:

1. Global Permissions - what people/groups/roles can do across the Jira application
2. Permission Schemes - what people can do in specific project(s)

In each place, note who can do what.

Hope this helps! I presume you're a global admin since you're setting up this Jira instance.